# select the last added element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a simple bit of code.  Nothing serious, or life-threatening.  I'm just trying to use JavaScript to fill out an empty html file with some basic 100x100 elements by clicking on the last element created.  Problem is: I can't actually get my code to register the last element created, only the last initial element.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Container Rainbow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div{ width:100px;height:100px; }
        #head{ background-color:rgba(100,0,100,.8);}
        #wrapper{width:100%;height:auto;}
        div#wrapper > div{float:left;}
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var lastDiv;
        var rgba = new Array();
        rgba[0] = 110; rgba[1] = 0; rgba[2] = 110; rgba[3] = 1;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            lastDiv = $("div").last();
            lastDiv.on("click", function(){
            rgba[0] += 5;
            rgba[2] += 5;
            var newDiv = $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("hatchling")
                    .css("background-color", "rgba("+rgba[0]+",0,"+rgba[2]+",1)")
            $(this).after(newDiv);
            lastDiv=newDiv;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="head"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that you may use and jsfiddle demonstrating how it works http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/K2dyd/

```
var lastDiv;
var rgba = new Array();
rgba[0] = 110; rgba[1] = 0; rgba[2] = 110; rgba[3] = 1;

var divClick = function() {
    rgba[0] += 5;
    rgba[2] += 5;
    var newDiv = $("<div></div>")
    .addClass("hatchling")
    .css("background-color", "rgba("+rgba[0]+",0,"+rgba[2]+",1)")
    $(this).after(newDiv);
    lastDiv.off("click");
    lastDiv=newDiv;
    lastDiv.on("click", divClick);
}

lastDiv = $("div").last();
lastDiv.on("click", divClick);
```

The idea is to attach the *onclick* event to the latest div. In your code you create the div and assign it to *lastDiv*, but there is no event handler attached.

Comment: Wonderful.  Haven't come across .off() before.  Much appreciated.  The world is safe once more thanks to... Krasimir!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to reduce my dependency on globe variables when possible. Here is an alternative answer.

**[Feddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K2dyd/2/)**

JavaScript :

```
var handleClick     =    function() 
                         {
                             var $this       = $(this);
                             var $newDiv     = $('<div></div>');
                             var rgba        =  $this.css('background-color').match(/\d+/ig);

                             rgba[0] = parseInt(rgba[0], 10) + 5;
                             rgba[2] = parseInt(rgba[2], 10) + 5;

                             $newDiv.addClass("hatchling");
                             $newDiv.css("background-color", "rgba("+rgba[0]+","+rgba[1]+","+rgba[2]+",1)");

                             $(this).after($newDiv);                           
                        };

$("#wrapper").on("click", "div:last", handleClick);
```

Comment: That's screwing with my brain.  This is just supposed to be a simple creation.  But that match() combined with parseInt() does give me a new idea.

Comment: The important thing to note is that I am using delegation to figure out which is the last div and not depending on globe variables, no matter what the click event will always be on the last div.